# Android view comparing two views for equality

Tags: android, android-layout

I have 4 buttons on a layout, and for each of the buttons, they have the attribute:

`android:onClick="numberChosen"`

now, what I had planned on doing was that in my activity (which uses a layout that has the 4 buttons), I have something like:

```
public class Blah extends Activity{
    String fileName;
    Button one;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_number_players_selection_screen);
        one = (Button) findViewById(R.id.number_players_one);
    }


    public void numberChosen(View v){
        if(v == one){                              // <-------- first way
            System.out.println("first way");      
        }
        if(v.getId()==R.id.number_players_one){    // <--------  second way
            System.out.println("second way");
        }
    }
}
```

if you take note of what happens in the method `numberChosen`, between these two ways, which one is better? or are they both exactly doing the same thing?

on a side note, is doing `android:onClick="numberChosen"` any better or worse than just setting the `View.onClickListener` instead?

Comment: Second way is more better approach than the first one. Also you can also implement onClickListner for in Blah class (i.e your activity)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From my point of view, both ways are correct, they get the job done.
From performance point view, the second way *might* be better.

In addition, like some suggested, using the **switch case** might not be possible if you are using ADT 14 or higher, in a library project, because the IDs are not final (constants), so you have to use if statements in that case only.

Answer (score 5):

I am using min SDK 14 and this solution is not working in some cases (work only for first row of my list adapter)

```
findViewById(R.id.item_icon_favourite) == view
```

solved by comparing with IDs

```
R.id.item_icon_favourite == view.getId()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    public class Blah extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
                String fileName;
                Button one;
                @Override
                public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_number_players_selection_screen);
                    one = (Button) findViewById(R.id.number_players_one);

one..setOnClickListener(this); // way 1 to do that

    // more better way would be customized for whole app 

    **one..setOnClickListener(new MyClickListener());**
                }


            /** The click event observer pattern for the different items on the view
                 * 
                 * @see android.view.View.OnClickListener#onClick(android.view.View)
                 */
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    switch (v.getId()) {
                    case R.id.number_players_one:

                        // best way 1
                        break;
            default :
            break;
            }

            } 

            }
```

A more custom implementation you can have a customized listener for different sections in the app as :

```
public class MyClickListener implements OnClickListener {
    private Context mContext;
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mContext = v.getContext();

        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.number_players_one:

        // best way 2 and more better among all
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: This answer is cleaner.  I was able to use this technique to have two recyclerview show different data, though the format was the same in the viewholder sense.  I set the IDs as an extra parameter for the adapter constructor, and created an instance of it for each recyclerview on the page.  In the adapter, it just sets the _viewholder_ id to the instance in the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `switch` case its more readable.Its does n't matter weather your are using `android:onClick="numberChosen"` or `View.onClickListener()`